# Receive emails to amazon s3 bucket select prefix according to mail id

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I have a rule in Amazon SES which copies all mails to a particular domain into an s3 bucket. I want to have subfolders inside this bucket and keep emails separately according to the email prefix.
For example my current rule takes all incoming mails of `anything@test.com` into s3 bucket `emaillist`. If email was sent to `customer1@test.com` I want to keep it in `emaillist/customer1` similarly for any other email in this domain I want to keep it in separate sub folders.
Can I do it without Lambda ?Only by using rule sets?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no - you need to use Lambda to create a dynamic prefix(subfolder).

Comment: Can u please help me with an example Lambda function which does this?

Comment: Short answer is no :) Long answer is use your google fu, try something and if you get stuck then post another, specific question SO.